# Mongoose .catch block is the same in multiple places. How do I avoid this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I use mongoose promises in my Node REST api and I have a lot of .catch blocks that are the same.

Here is a short route:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Post.find()
        .populate('category', 'name')
        .exec()
        .then(posts => {
            res.status(200).json(posts);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            log.error(err);
            res.status(500).json(err);
        });
});
```

I have some routes where that exact .catch block appears three times in the same function.
Can I create a function where to have the log and result and pass the function to the .catch? Or can I use some middleware? How can I clean my code a bit?

Here is the mess:

```
router.delete('/:commentId', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    // Find the comment
    Comment.findById(req.params.commentId).exec()
        .then(comment => {
            foundComment = comment;

            // Delete the comment
            Comment.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.commentId }).exec()
                .then(result => {
                    if (result.deletedCount) {

                        // If the comment has replies, remove them as well
                        if (foundComment.replies.length > 0) {
                            Comment.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: foundComment.replies } }).exec()
                                .then(result => {
                                    if (result.deletedCount) {
                                        res.status(200).json({
                                            deletedCount: result.deletedCount + 1
                                        });
                                    }
                                })
                                .catch(err => {
                                    log.error(err);
                                    res.status(500).json(err);
                                });

                            return;
                        }

                        res.status(200).json({
                            deletedCount: result.deletedCount
                        });
                    } else {
                        res.status(404).json({
                            message: `Comment with id ${req.params.commentId} doesn't exist.`
                        });
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    log.error(err);
                    res.status(500).json(err);
                });

        })
        .catch(err => {
            log.error(err);
            res.status(500).json(err);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return each of the Promises in the Promise chain, so that they're all tied together, allowing you to put a single `.catch` at the very end, which will run if anything throws inside:

```
router.delete('/:commentId', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
  let foundComment;
  Comment.findById(req.params.commentId).exec()
    .then(comment => {
      foundComment = comment;
      return Comment.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.commentId }).exec();
    })
  .then(result => {
    if (!result.deletedCount) {
      res.status(404).json({
        message: `Comment with id ${req.params.commentId} doesn't exist.`
      });
      return;
    }
    if (foundComment.replies.length <= 0) {
      res.status(200).json({
        deletedCount: result.deletedCount
      });
      return;
    }
    return Comment.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: foundComment.replies } }).exec()
      .then(result => {
      if (result.deletedCount) {
        res.status(200).json({
          deletedCount: result.deletedCount + 1
        });
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    log.error(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  });
});
```

Generally, try to avoid nesting `.then`s if you can help it - flatter code is more readable code. `async`/`await` will make things even clearer:

```
router.delete('/:commentId', checkAuth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const foundComment = await Comment.findById(req.params.commentId).exec();
    const deleteOneResult = await Comment.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.commentId }).exec();
    if (!deleteOneResult.deletedCount) {
      res.status(404).json({
        message: `Comment with id ${req.params.commentId} doesn't exist.`
      });
      return;
    }
    if (foundComment.replies.length <= 0) {
      res.status(200).json({
        deletedCount: result.deletedCount
      });
      return;
    }
    const deleteManyResult = await Comment.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: foundComment.replies } }).exec()
    if (deleteManyResult.deletedCount) {
      res.status(200).json({
        deletedCount: deleteManyResult.deletedCount + 1
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    log.error(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing your code to use `async/await` and use `try/catch` to handle error.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let posts = await Post.find().populate('category', 'name');
        let comment = await Comment.findById(req.params.commentId);
        if (!comment) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: `Comment with id ${req.params.commentId} doesn't exist.`
            });
        }
        // Another query...
        res.status(200).json(posts);
    } catch(err) {
        log.error(err);
        res.status(500).json(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a function directly to `.catch` like:

```
function handleError(err) {
  console.error('the error:', err.message)
}

const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(new Error('your error')))

promise.catch(handleError)
```

Comment: Ok... But what do I do with the `res.status(500).json(err);` thing?

Comment: One way would be to define your function inside the router.delete function so you have access to `res`.